# jquery $.action.<HREF> a click to anchor tag

Tags: jquery

I have been taking over some node.js code from another coder, and I stumbled upon a trick for which I don't manage to understand the mechanism.

The project is using node.js 0.8.25 / jQuery 1.6.2 (if that should matter)

When I add the anchor (in that particular project)

```
<a href="#clickme">Click ME</a>
```

and the jQuery code is

```
$.action.clickme = function (e, tail) {
    alert('hello world!');
};
```

NOTE: I am adding the `clickme` function to the action namespace, where `clickme` is also the `HREF` in my anchor

If I click on that link in the context of my project, 
it triggers the OnClick event and shows the 'Hello word' alert (??)

So $.action. automatically 'resolves' the hook to the anchor with href='#HREF' (How is this possible??)

I have tried to fiddle out side the project but I don't manage to reproduce this behaviour, so there is a trick somewhere in the code that may implement this mechanism.

Any help on how to figure this out would be great.

Comment: Do you want to register a click event on anchor using `jquery` ?

Comment: No I know how to do that. All I am saying is that if I add this few lines of code, it actually works and I can't understand why, and how this is done. I have been studying the code for hours.

Answer (score 2):

you could use delegate to future bind elements with # (maybe you would want to have a[href] as a selector? and also maybe want to check if the hash actually targets a function that exists?:

```
$(document).delegate('a[href=^="#"]', 'click', function(event){
    var action = $.action[this.hash.substring(1)];
    if(action) {
        action.call(this, event);
    }
});
```

if you use/update to jquery 1.7+:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[href=^="#"]', function(event){
    var action = $.action[this.hash.substring(1)];
    if(action) {
        action.call(this, event);
    }
});
```

and you can use this in your methods:

```
$.action.clickme = function (e, tail) {
    alert('hello world!' + this.href); // this is the a-element that was clicked on
};
```

Comment: Using jQuery 2.2 I had to escape the # like so: `a[href^=\\#]`

Answer (score 0):

It took me ages to find out but
here the missing piece of code I was looking for

```
$("[href^=#]").bind( "click", function() {
    $.action[this.hash.substring(1)]();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QaB86/

Selector, find all anchors href: `$("[href^=#]")`

Bind click to namespaced function: `bind( "click"`

Take the # from the href : `this.hash.substring(1)`

substring removes the first character.

Now I need to find something similar in the context of the code I am taking over.